# How to get total number of rows with data in a sheet using gsheets dart library?

Tags: flutter, dart, gsheets

Using the [gsheets](https://pub.dev/packages/gsheets) library, I can calculate the total number of rows in a specific sheet:

```dart
var sheet = ss.worksheetByTitle('test');
var rows = await sheet?.values.map.allRows();
var totalRows = rows?.length;
```

However, the above code requires fetching the row data from the sheet. Is it possible to get the total number of rows without fetching the actual data?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Worksheet().rowCount;`

I found it in this file [Gsheets](https://github.com/a-marenkov/gsheets/blob/master/lib/src/gsheets.dart)
[image: here]

Comment: It returns total number of rows, even the ones that have no data.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do this by allRow method
here is an example:
//get worksheetbytitle first!
var allRows = await _workSheet?.values.map.allRows();
var totalRows = allRows?.length;
// print row data
for (var i = 0; i < allRows!.length; i++) {
print(allRows[i]);
}

1. List item